# Responsive sprite animation GSAP

Tags: css, responsive-design, sprite, css-sprites, gsap

I have a sprite that I am animating using greenbacks [GSAP Tween platform](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/invalidate/). The spite contains 7 different images which is then used to create an animation. Each image on the sprite is `1000px` by `1000px` in size.

Here is the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="animate-wrapper">
    <img src="test.svg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#animate-wrapper {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#animate-wrapper img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 700%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var animateTongueOut = new TimelineMax({paused: true});
var easeTongueOut = new SteppedEase(6);
animateTongueOut.to('#animate-wrapper img', 1, {
    x: '-6000px',
    ease: easeTongueOut
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a sprite as a background image and then used GSAP to animate as a image sequence by changing the "backgroundPosition".

```
var flyingPoni = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

for (var poniX = 1; poniX < 10; poniX++) {
      flyingPoni.to($(".poni"), 0, {
        backgroundPosition:(-300*poniX)+"px",
        ease: "easeOutQuint",delay:.065} );
};
```

link of demo: http://codepen.io/Keinchy/pen/xGbpmK

hope this helps, cheers.